# content disappears when browser's window is resized

Tags: javascript, html, browser, resize

I'm making a website and I have a little problem with it.
When I open it on my browser with full sized window it has no problem but, when I change the size of my window and make it smaller, the texts disappears and the image content size changes.

Must be something with the javascript or css. Please give me an advice if you can see any solution to this problem.

Thanks!

---

Here's the HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
        <title>Untitled Document</title>
        <link href="../css/style.css" rel="stylesheet"
        type="text/css" />
        <script src="../css/SpryTabbedPanels.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <link href="../css/SpryTabbedPanels.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
        />
        <link rel='stylesheet' id='NextGEN-css' href='http://www.markandlona.com/core/wp-content/plugins/nextgen-gallery/css/nggallery.css?ver=1.0.0'
        type='text/css' media='screen' />
        <link rel='stylesheet' id='colorpicker.css-css' href='http://www.markandlona.com/core/wp-content/themes/crius/js/colorpicker/css/colorpicker.css?ver=1.2'
        type='text/css' media='all' />
        <link rel='stylesheet' id='fancybox_css-css' href='http://www.markandlona.com/core/wp-content/themes/crius/js/fancybox/jquery.fancybox.css?ver=1.2'
        type='text/css' media='all' />
        <link rel='stylesheet' id='fancybox_thumb_css-css' href='http://www.markandlona.com/core/wp-content/themes/crius/js/fancybox/jquery.fancybox-thumbs.css?ver=1.2'
        type='text/css' media='all' />
        <link rel='stylesheet' id='grid_css-css' href='../css/grid.css' type='text/css'
        media='all' />
        <link rel='stylesheet' id='google_fonts-css' href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Alice&#038;ver=3.3.2'
        type='text/css' media='all' />
        <link rel='stylesheet' id='jquery.lightbox.min.css-css' href='http://www.markandlona.com/core/wp-content/plugins/wp-jquery-lightbox/styles/lightbox.min.css?ver=1.3.4'
        type='text/css' media='all' />
        <script type='text/javascript' src='http://www.markandlona.com/core/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js?ver=1.7.1'></script>
        <script type='text/javascript' src='http://www.markandlona.com/core/wp-content/plugins/nextgen-gallery/js/jquery.cycle.all.min.js?ver=2.9995'></script>
        <script type='text/javascript' src='http://www.markandlona.com/core/wp-content/plugins/nextgen-gallery/js/ngg.slideshow.min.js?ver=1.06'></script>
        <script type='text/javascript' src='http://www.markandlona.com/core/wp-content/themes/crius/js/jquery.ui.js?ver=1.2'></script>
        <script type='text/javascript' src='http://www.markandlona.com/core/wp-content/themes/crius/js/colorpicker.js?ver=1.2'></script>
        <script type='text/javascript' src='http://www.markandlona.com/core/wp-content/themes/crius/js/fancybox/jquery.fancybox.pack.js?ver=1.2'></script>
        <script type='text/javascript' src='http://www.markandlona.com/core/wp-content/themes/crius/js/fancybox/jquery.fancybox-thumbs.js?ver=1.2'></script>
        <script type='text/javascript' src='http://www.markandlona.com/core/wp-content/themes/crius/js/jquery.easing.js?ver=1.2'></script>
        <script type='text/javascript' src='http://www.markandlona.com/core/wp-content/themes/crius/js/jquery.nivoslider.js?ver=1.2'></script>
        <script type='text/javascript' src='http://www.markandlona.com/core/wp-content/themes/crius/js/jquery.touchwipe.1.1.1.js?ver=1.2'></script>
        <script type='text/javascript' src='http://www.markandlona.com/core/wp-content/themes/crius/js/jquery.validate.js?ver=1.2'></script>
        <script type='text/javascript' src='http://www.markandlona.com/core/wp-content/themes/crius/js/browser.js?ver=1.2'></script>
        <script type='text/javascript' src='http://www.markandlona.com/core/wp-content/themes/crius/js/jquery.backstretch.js?ver=1.2'></script>
        <script type='text/javascript' src='http://www.markandlona.com/core/wp-content/themes/crius/js/hint.js?ver=1.2'></script>
        <script type='text/javascript' src='http://www.markandlona.com/core/wp-content/themes/crius/js/jquery.flip.min.js?ver=1.2'></script>
        <script type='text/javascript' src='http://www.markandlona.com/core/wp-content/themes/crius/js/fancybox/jquery.mousewheel-3.0.6.pack.js?ver=1.2'></script>
        <script type='text/javascript' src='http://www.markandlona.com/core/wp-content/themes/crius/js/jquery.jplayer.min.js?ver=1.2'></script>
        <script type='text/javascript' src='http://www.markandlona.com/core/wp-content/themes/crius/js/kenburns.js?ver=1.2'></script>
        <script type='text/javascript' src='http://www.markandlona.com/core/wp-content/themes/crius/js/jwplayer.js?ver=1.2'></script>
        <script type='text/javascript' src='../css/custom.js'></script>
        <style type="text/css">
            .post_header h2, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5 {
                color: #222222;
            }
            .nav li a {
                font-size:30px;
            }
            .nav li ul li a {
                font-size:21px;
            }
            h1 {
                font-size:40px;
            }
            h2 {
                font-size:32px;
            }
            h3 {
                font-size:26px;
            }
            h4 {
                font-size:24px;
            }
            h5 {
                font-size:22px;
            }
            h6 {
                font-size:18px;
            }
            a {
                color:#000000;
                font-family:"ヒラギノ角ゴ Pro W3", "Hiragino Kaku Gothic Pro", メイリオ, Meiryo, Osaka, "ＭＳ Ｐゴシック", "MS PGothic", sans-serif;
            }
            #nav_wrapper, #thin_nav, .post_date {
                background: #ffffff;
                overflow: visible;
                position: absolute;
                visibility: visible;
                width: 310px;
            }
            input[type=submit], input[type=button], a.button {
                background: #000000;
                text-shadow: -1px 0 1px #333;
            }
            input[type=submit], input[type=button], a.button {
                color: #ffffff;
            }
            input[type=submit]:hover, input[type=button]:hover, a.button:hover {
                color: #ffffff;
            }
            input[type=submit], input[type=button], a.button {
                border: 1px solid #111111;
            }
            .post_header h2, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5 {
                color: #222222;
            }
            h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, .nav li a, #kenburns_title, #kenburns_desc, .personal_contact h6 {
                font-family:'Alice';
            }
            h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, .nav li a, #gallery_title, #gallery_desc, .nav li a, .nav_page_number li {
                text-transform: none;
            }
            .nav li a, .nav_page_number li {
                color: #000000;
            }
            .nav li ul {
                border-left: 1px solid #000000;
            }
            .nav li.current-menu-item > a, .nav li > a:hover, .nav li > a.hover, .nav li > a:active, .nav li.current-menu-parent > a, .nav li.current-menu-item ul li a:hover, .nav li ul li a:hover, .nav li ul li:hover a, .nav li ul li.current-menu-item a {
                color: #ff8e01;
            }
            h1.menu_header, #footer {
                color: #919191;
            }
        </style>
        <link href="../css/screen.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
        />
        <style type="text/css">
            h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
                font-family: Dosis;
            }
        </style>
    </head>

    <body>
        <!-- Begin logo -->
        <!-- End logo -->
        <!-- Begin main nav -->
        <div id="nav_wrapper">
            <div class="nav_wrapper_inner">
                <div id="menu_border_wrapper">  <a id="custom_logo" class="logo_wrapper" href="http://www.markandlona.com/core"><img src="../images/verrisgolf_small.jpg" alt="" width="151" height="42"/></a>

                    <ul
                    id="main_menu" class="nav">
                        <li id="menu-item-418" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page current-menu-item page_item page-item-2 current_page_item menu-item-418"><a href="http://www.markandlona.com/core/">HOME</a>
                        </li>
                        <li id="menu-item-87" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-87"><a href="http://www.markandlona.com/core/about">ABOUT</a> 
                        </li>
                        <li id="menu-item-92" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-92"><a href="http://www.markandlona.com/core/visual">COLLECTIONS</a>

                            <ul class="sub-menu">
                                <li id="menu-item-93" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-93"><a href="http://www.markandlona.com/core/visual/models">A/W 2012</a>
                                </li>
                                <li id="menu-item-94" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-94"><a href="http://www.markandlona.com/core/visual/movie">S/S 2012</a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li id="menu-item-95" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-95"><a href="http://www.markandlona.com/core/product%ef%bc%8b">ARCHIVES</a>

                            <ul
                            class="sub-menu">
                                <li id="menu-item-96" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-96"><a href="http://www.markandlona.com/core/product%ef%bc%8b/men">A/W 2011</a>
                                </li>
                                <li id="menu-item-97" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-97"><a href="http://www.markandlona.com/core/product%ef%bc%8b/women">S/S 2011</a>
                                </li>
                                <li id="menu-item-" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-96"><a href="http://www.markandlona.com/core/product%ef%bc%8b/men">A/W 2010</a>
                                </li>
                                <li id="menu-item-2" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-97"><a href="http://www.markandlona.com/core/product%ef%bc%8b/women">S/S 2010</a>
                                </li>
                                </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li id="menu-item-101" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-101"><a href="http://www.markandlona.com/core/press%ef%bc%8b">BLOG</a>

                        </li>
                        <li id="menu-item-104" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-104"><a href="http://www.markandlona.com/core/news">ONLINE STORE</a>
                        </li>
                        <li id="menu-item-519" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-519"><a href="http://www.markandlona.com/core/shoplist">SHOP LIST</a>
                        </li>
                        </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        </div>
    </body>

</html>
```

Here's my JavaScript:

```
var $j = jQuery.noConflict();

/* jquery.imagefit 
 *
 * Version 0.2 by Oliver Boermans <http://www.ollicle.com/eg/jquery/imagefit/>
 *
 * Extends jQuery <http://jquery.com>
 *
 */
(function($) {
    $.fn.imagefit = function(options) {
        var fit = {
            all : function(imgs){
                imgs.each(function(){
                    fit.one(this);
                    })
                },
            one : function(img){
                $(img)
                    .width('100%').each(function()
                    {
                        $(this).height(Math.round(
                            $(this).attr('startheight')*($(this).width()/$(this).attr('startwidth')))
                        );
                    })
                }
        };

        this.each(function(){
                var container = this;

                // store list of contained images (excluding those in tables)
                var imgs = $('img', container).not($("table img"));

                // store initial dimensions on each image 
                imgs.each(function(){
                    $(this).attr('startwidth', $(this).width())
                        .attr('startheight', $(this).height())
                        .css('max-width', $(this).attr('startwidth')+"px");

                    fit.one(this);
                });
                // Re-adjust when window width is changed
                $(window).bind('resize', function(){
                    fit.all(imgs);
                });
            });
        return this;
    };
})(jQuery);

$j.fn.getIndex = function(){
    var $jp=$j(this).parent().children();
    return $jp.index(this);
}

jQuery.fn.extend({
  slideRight: function() {
    return this.each(function() {
        jQuery(this).show();
    });
  },
  slideLeft: function() {
    return this.each(function() {
        jQuery(this).hide();
    });
  },
  slideToggleWidth: function() {
    return this.each(function() {
      var el = jQuery(this);
      if (el.css('display') == 'block') {
        el.slideRight();
      } else {
        el.slideLeft();
      }
    });
  }
});

$j.fn.setNav = function(){
    $j('#main_menu li ul').css({display: 'none'});

    $j('#main_menu li').each(function()
    {   
        var $jsublist = $j(this).find('ul:first');

        $j(this).hover(function()
        {   
            $jsublist.css({opacity: 1});

            $jsublist.stop().css({overflow:'visible', height:'auto', display:'none'}).fadeIn(200, function()
            {
                $j(this).css({overflow:'visible', height:'auto', display: 'block'});
            }); 
        },
        function()
        {   
            $jsublist.stop().css({overflow:'visible', height:'auto', display:'none'}).fadeOut(200, function()
            {
                $j(this).css({overflow:'visible', display:'none'});
            }); 
        }); 

    });

    $j('#main_menu li').each(function()
    {

        $j(this).hover(function()
        {   
            $j(this).find('a:first').addClass('hover');
        },
        function()
        {   
            $j(this).find('a:first').removeClass('hover');
        }); 

    });

    $j('#menu_wrapper .nav ul li ul').css({display: 'none'});

    $j('#menu_wrapper .nav ul li').each(function()
    {   

        var $jsublist = $j(this).find('ul:first');

        $j(this).hover(function()
        {   
            $jsublist.css({opacity: 1});

            $jsublist.stop().css({overflow:'visible', height:'auto', display:'none'}).fadeIn(200, function()
            {
                $j(this).css({overflow:'visible', height:'auto', display: 'block'});
            }); 
        },
        function()
        {   
            $jsublist.stop().css({overflow:'visible', height:'auto', display:'none'}).fadeOut(200, function()
            {
                $j(this).css({overflow:'visible', display:'none'});
            }); 
        }); 

    });

    $j('#menu_wrapper .nav ul li').each(function()
    {

        $j(this).hover(function()
        {   
            $j(this).find('a:first').addClass('hover');
        },
        function()
        {   
            $j(this).find('a:first').removeClass('hover');
        }); 

    });
}

$j(document).ready(function(){ 

    $j(document).setNav();

    $j('#thin_nav').mouseenter(
        function() {
            setTimeout(function() {
                $j('#nav_wrapper').animate({"right": "0px"}, { duration: 300 });
                $j(this).css('display', 'none');
            }, 300);
        }
    );

    $j('#nav_wrapper').mouseleave(
        function() {
            $j(this).animate({"right": "-250px"}, { duration: 300 });
            $j('#thin_nav').css('display', 'block');
        }
    );

    $j('#nav_wrapper').touchwipe({
        wipeRight: function(){ 
            $j('#nav_wrapper').animate({"right": "-250px"}, { duration: 300 });
            $j('#thin_nav').css('display', 'block');
        }
    });

    $j('#thin_nav').touchwipe({
        wipeLeft: function(){ 
            $j('#nav_wrapper').animate({"right": "0px"}, { duration: 300 });
            $j('#thin_nav').css('display', 'none');
        }
    });

    $j('.pp_gallery a').fancybox({ 
        padding: 0,
        overlayColor: '#000', 
        transitionIn: 'fade',
        transitionOut: 'fade',
        overlayOpacity: 0.9
    });

    $j('.flickr li a').fancybox({ 
        prevEffect  : 'none',
        nextEffect  : 'none',
        helpers : {
            title   : {
                type: 'outside'
            },
            overlay : {
                opacity : 0.9,
                css : {
                    'background-color' : '#000'
                }
            },
            thumbs  : {
                width   : 60,
                height  : 60
            }
        }
    });

    $j('a.fancy-gallery').fancybox({ 
        prevEffect  : 'none',
        nextEffect  : 'none',
        helpers : {
            title   : {
                type: 'outside'
            },
            overlay : {
                opacity : 0.9,
                css : {
                    'background-color' : '#000'
                }
            },
            thumbs  : {
                width   : 60,
                height  : 60
            }
        }
    });

    $j('.img_frame').fancybox({ 
        padding: 0,
        overlayColor: '#000', 
        overlayOpacity: 0.9
    });

    $j('.lightbox_youtube').fancybox({ 
        padding: 0,
        overlayColor: '#000', 
        transitionIn: 'fade',
        transitionOut: 'fade',
        overlayOpacity: 0.9,
        scrolling: 'no'
    });

    $j('.lightbox_vimeo').fancybox({ 
        padding: 0,
        overlayColor: '#000', 
        transitionIn: 'fade',
        transitionOut: 'fade',
        overlayOpacity: 0.9,
        scrolling: 'no'
    });

    $j('.project_single').fancybox({ 
        padding: 0,
        overlayColor: '#000', 
        transitionIn: 'fade',
        transitionOut: 'fade',
        overlayOpacity: 0.9,
        scrolling: 'no'
    });

    $j('input[title!=""]').hint();

    $j('textarea[title!=""]').hint();

    $j('.one_fourth.gallery4').hover(
        function(){
            var $jthis = $j(this);
            $jthis.children('a').children('img').stop().animate({
                    'height':'185px',
                    'top':'0px',
                    'left':'0px'
                }, 400);

        },
        function(){
            var $jthis = $j(this);
            $jthis.children('a').children('img').stop().animate({
                'height':'200px',
                'top':'0px',
                'left':'0px'
                }, 400);
        }
    );

    $j('.one_third.gallery3').hover(
        function(){
            var $jthis = $j(this);
            $jthis.children('a').children('img').stop().animate({
                    'height':'240px',
                    'top':'0px',
                    'left':'0px'
                }, 400);
        },
        function(){
            var $jthis = $j(this);
            $jthis.children('a').children('img').stop().animate({
                    'height':'260px',
                    'top':'0px',
                    'left':'0px'
                }, 400);
        }
    );

    $j('.one_half.gallery2').hover(
        function(){
            var $jthis = $j(this);
            $jthis.children('a').children('img').stop().animate({
                    'height':'320px',
                    'top':'0px',
                    'left':'0px'
                }, 400);
        },
        function(){
            var $jthis = $j(this);
            $jthis.children('a').children('img').stop().animate({
                'height':'340px',
                'top':'0px',
                'left':'0px'
                }, 400);
        }
    );


    //Firefoxがフリーズするのでブロック
    //$j('.post_img').hover(
//      function(){
//          var $jthis = $j(this);
//          $jthis.children('a').children('img').stop().animate({
//                  'height':'250px',
//                  'top':'0px',
//                  'left':'0px'
//              }, 400);
//      },
//      function(){
//          var $jthis = $j(this);
//          $jthis.children('a').children('img').stop().animate({
//              'height':'260px',
//              'top':'0px',
//              'left':'0px'
//              }, 400);
//      }
//  );

    //$j('.post_img').click(
//      function(event){
//          $j(this).children('a').trigger('click');
//      }
//  );

    var calScreenHeight = $j(window).height()-108;
    $j('#page_content_wrapper').css('top', '0px');

    setTimeout(function() {
        $j('#menu_wrapper').fadeIn();
        $j('#jp_interface_1').fadeIn();
        $j('#controls').fadeIn();
        $j('#page_content_wrapper').fadeIn();
        $j('.page_control').fadeIn();
        $j('#page_maximize').trigger('click');
        $j('#tray-button').trigger('click');
    }, 1012);

    var miniRightPos = 1012;

    $j('#page_minimize').click(function(){
        var calScreenHeight = $j(window).height()-120;

        $j(this).css('display', 'none');
        $j('#page_maximize').css('display', 'block');
        $j('#page_content_wrapper').animate({ 'left': -miniRightPos+'px' }, 200);
        $j('.page_control').animate({ 'left': '332px' }, 0);
        $j('.personal_contact').fadeOut('slow');
        $j('.gallery_social').fadeOut('slow');
        $j('#kenburns_title').fadeIn('slow');
        $j('#kenburns_desc').fadeIn('slow');
    });

    $j('#page_maximize').click(function(){
        var calScreenHeight = $j(window).height()-120;

        $j(this).css('display', 'none');
        $j('#page_minimize').css('display', 'block');
        $j('#page_content_wrapper').animate({ 'left': '332px' }, 400);
        $j('.page_control').animate({ 'left': miniRightPos+'px' }, 400);
        $j('.personal_contact').fadeIn('slow');
        $j('.gallery_social').fadeIn('slow');
        $j('#kenburns_title').fadeOut('slow');
        $j('#kenburns_desc').fadeOut('slow');
    });

    // Create the dropdown base
    $j("<select />").appendTo("#menu_border_wrapper");

    // Create default option "Go to..."
    $j("<option />", {
       "selected": "selected",
       "value"   : "",
       "text"    : "- Main Menu -"
    }).appendTo("#menu_border_wrapper select");

    // Populate dropdown with menu items
    $j(".nav li").each(function() {
     var current_item = $j(this).hasClass('current-menu-item'); 
     var el = $j(this).children('a');
     var menu_text = el.text();

     if($j(this).parent('ul.sub-menu').length > 0)
     {
        menu_text = "- "+menu_text;
        $j('ul.sub-menu li').css('display', 'block');
     }

     if($j(this).parent('ul.sub-menu').parent('li').parent('ul.sub-menu').length > 0)
     {
        menu_text = el.text();
        menu_text = "- - "+menu_text;

     }

     if(current_item)
     {
        $j("<option />", {
             "selected": "selected",
             "value"   : el.attr("href"),
             "text"    : menu_text
         }).appendTo("#menu_border_wrapper select");
     }
     else
     {
        $j("<option />", {
            "value"   : el.attr("href"),
            "text"    : menu_text
        }).appendTo("#menu_border_wrapper select");
     }
    });

    $j("#menu_border_wrapper select").change(function() {
        window.location = $j(this).find("option:selected").val();
    });

    //  $j('.sub-menu').touchwipe({
//          wipeRight: function(){ 
//              $j('.sub-menu').animate({"left": "0px"}, { duration: 300 });
//          $j('ul.sub-menu').css('display', 'block');
//          }
//    });
//    

});
```

Comment: Yikes: Read this http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#num_http

Comment: No one is going to look at 100's lines of code and when you are using 100's of plugins. You got to narrow it down.

Answer (score 0):

There could be several reasons why that's happening, but can I just point out the performance of your web pages will be horrible with that many http requests.

You need to bundle your css and js files and compress them at the minimum, and have some kind of cache strategy.  I highly recommend you look into this topic.